# Unable to send MPTCP packet with Scapy sendp()

Tags: python, networking, tcp, scapy

I captured an Multi-Path TCP traffic in a pcap file with a modified kernel supporting MPTCP. The layer 2 headers of a packet in that traffic with `Scapy` gives something like below which I'm unable to understand as it's not like an Ethernet Header.

```
>>> p = sniff(offline="my.pcap", count=1)[0]
>>> p.show()
###[ cooked linux ]###
  pkttype   = sent-by-us
  lladdrtype= 0x1
  lladdrlen = 6
  src       = '4@\xb5\x8e\x15\x92'
  proto     = IPv4
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4L
     ihl       = 5L
...
...
...
```

When I try to send the above packet using `sendp()`, I'm unable to see anything in my dump (both tcpdump and Wireshark). I think, since there is no destination mac address, `sendp()` is unable to send. But destination ip address is there. And when I try to send with send(), it shows an warning: `"WARNING: Mac address to reach destination not found. Using broadcast."`

But since, I've captured that packet from a live traffic using `tcpdump`, how there it's being sent with only the destination ip address? is there any workaround for it in Scapy/Python?

I would also like some suggestions for working with MPTCP in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pcap file used has incorrect packets. Booted with an MPTCP enabled kernel and did a fresh test. This is what I got from the MPTCP packets which contains valid Ethernet addresses.

```
>>> ack_pkt = sniff(offline="../mptcp/mptcpdemo.pcap", count=14)[0]
>>> ack_pkt.show()
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = 00:**:**:**:**:44
  src       = 34:**:**:**:**:92
  type      = IPv4
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4L
     ihl       = 5L
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 72
...
...
...
###[ TCP ]###
...
...
...
   options   = [('MSS', 1460), ('SAckOK', ''), ('Timestamp', (523099492, 0)),
   ('NOP', None), ('WScale', 7), (30, '\x00\x81\x8bxb\xdfZ\xbdS\t')]
```

The last part of Options contains `Kind=30` which says that this is an MPTCP packet.